# Bitcoin Cash - Trying to implement Explorer in Linux server but getting error

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-cash, bitcoin-core-development

I have tried to setup bitcoin cash explorer in my Linux server and server start working for 5 minutes but after 5 minutes it is returning an error and I have configured explorer-API and it is not working properly in the background.

### Error Facing:

```
[2018-02-09T13:32:31.589Z] info: Using config: /home/kiran/bchnode/bch-node.json
[2018-02-09T13:32:31.590Z] info: Using network: testnet
[2018-02-09T13:32:31.591Z] info: Starting bitcoind
[2018-02-09T13:32:31.592Z] info: Using bitcoin config file: 
/home/kiran/bchnode/data/bitcoin.conf
[2018-02-09T13:37:26.959Z] error: Failed to start services
[2018-02-09T13:37:26.960Z] error: RPCError: Bitcoin JSON-RPC: Request 
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:18332
    at Bitcoin._wrapRPCError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@owstack/bch-
node/lib/services/bitcoind.js:447:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@owstack/bch-
node/lib/services/bitcoind.js:779:28
    at newCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@owstack/bch-
node/node_modules/@owstack/bitcoind-rpc/lib/index.js:52:16)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> 
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@owstack/bch-
node/node_modules/@owstack/bitcoind-rpc/lib/index.js:136:7)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:160:13)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:389:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:160:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19)
[2018-02-09T13:37:26.961Z] info: Beginning shutdown
[2018-02-09T13:37:26.961Z] info: Stopping @owstack/bch-explorer-api 
(not started)
[2018-02-09T13:37:26.962Z] info: Stopping web (not started)
[2018-02-09T13:37:26.962Z] info: Stopping bitcoind
[2018-02-09T13:37:26.962Z] info: Halted
```

### bch-node.json file

```
{
  "network": "testnet",
  "port": 3007,
  "services": [
    "@owstack/bch-explorer-api",
    "bitcoind",
    "web"
  ],
  "servicesConfig": {
    "bitcoind": {
      "spawn": {
        "datadir": "./data",
        "exec": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@owstack/bchnode/bin/bitcoind"
      }
    },
    "explorer-api": {
       "rateLimiterOptions": {
         "whitelist": ["::ffff:127.0.0.1"]
       }
     }
  }
}
```

### bitcoin.conf file

```
server=1
whitelist=127.0.0.1
txindex=1
addressindex=1
timestampindex=1
spentindex=1
zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.2:28332
zmqpubhashblock=tcp://127.0.0.2:28332
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcuser=bitcoin
rpcpassword=local321
uacomment=bch
```

### Installation Process:

```
npm install -g @owstack/bch-node
bchnode create -d <bitcoin-data-dir> mynode
cd mynode
bchnode install https://github.com/owstack/bch-explorer-api.git
bchnode start
```

It should run "http://localhost:3007/bch-explorer-api/" but it is not returning anything and it is getting error after 5 minutes in my linux terminal.

Please help me about this error related bitcoin cash block explorer.

I am trying to configure https://bch-insight.bitpay.com this explorer in my local server If you have any reference github link then please share with me because I m not able to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try replacing `bch-node.json` file with this:

```
{
  "network": "testnet",
  "port": 3007,
  "services": [
    "@owstack/bch-explorer-api",
    "bitcoind",
    "web"
  ],
  "servicesConfig": {
    "bitcoind": {
      "spawn": {
        "datadir": "./data",
        "exec": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@owstack/bch-node/bin/bitcoind"
      }
    },
    "explorer-api": {
       "rateLimiterOptions": {
         "whitelist": ["::ffff:127.0.0.1"]
       }
    },
    "fee": {
      "rpc": {
        "user": "bitcoin",
        "pass": "local321",
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "protocol": "http",
        "port": 18332
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Because Bitcore won't be able to connect to your node without knowing your RPC username and password.

Comment: Can you explain what changes have been made to fix the problem?  It makes it easier for everyone to see what the problem was, and what the solution is.

Comment: @MCCCS  Facing same issue after editing bch-node.json file.

Comment: @kiranmalvi Try asking it here: https://github.com/bitpay/insight-api/issues

Comment: @MCCCS: Solved issue as you suggested